# Javascript String Split |

Tags: javascript, string, code-splitting

trying to split: 
`"fundernumber": "Main: 01234567890|Breakdown: 01234567890|Other: 01234567890" }`
on to three separate lines using a linebreak.

HTML -
    span id="fundno"

Javascript -

```
$('#fundno').append(data.fundernumber);

var numbers = data.fundernumber;
var numbersplit = numbers.split("|");

var i;
var newstring = "";
for (i = 0; i < numbersplit.length; i++) {
    newstring += numbersplit[i]; + $<br>
        }

        $numbers.append(newstring)

});
```

});

Thanks

Comment: The code you've pasted has syntax errors...

Comment: This is very new to me could you please be more specific on which part. Many Thanks

Comment: @Stubot open the developer console and try to run the code. It will point you to the errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```js
var obj = {"fundernumber": "Main: 01234567890|Breakdown: 01234567890|Other: 01234567890" }

console.log(obj.fundernumber.split('|').join('\n'));
```

Read more about [`array.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I would do this by splitting the string and creating a ul,

```js
var origData = {"fundernumber": "Main: 01234567890|Breakdown: 01234567890|Other: 01234567890" }

var alteredData = origData.fundernumber.split('|');

var dataStr = '';
alteredData.forEach(function(data){
  dataStr += '<li>' + data + '</li>';
  })

document.getElementById('fundno').innerHTML = dataStr;
```

```css
#fundno {
 list-style: none;
 padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="fundno"></ul>
```

you can simply replace the pipe with a line break character using .replace?

```js
var origData = {"fundernumber": "Main: 01234567890|Breakdown: 01234567890|Other: 01234567890" }

var alteredData = origData.fundernumber.replace(/\|/g,'<br/>');

document.getElementById('fundno').innerHTML = alteredData;
```

```html
<span id="fundno"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use split() method that is used to split the string into an array of sub strings. Have a look at code below:

```html
<html>
    <body>

    <p>Click the button to display the array values 
    after the split.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var str = "Main:01234567890|Breakdown: 01234567890|Other: 01234567890";
    var text = "";
    var res = str.split("|");
    for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =           
    text += res[i] + "<br>";
        }
    
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```